# finding a function representing a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find a rule to extract a function from a simple sequence. The ones like 2n, 3n-1, n^2, 2^n etc are fairly easy to find but when it comes to sequences like [2,4,7,11,16,...] that translate to an=1/2n(n+1)+1 it's a tough job.

Is there a rule of thumb to find the arguments of a function representing a sequence in the form of an^2+bn+c?

Thanks/Brgds

Comment: If you start from $n=0$ then you have $a*0^2+b*0+c=2,a*1^2+b*1^2+c=4,a*2^2+b*2+c=7$ Now you have 3 equations with 3 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that the formula for $a_n$ is of polynomial type (degree $m$), you can try polynomial interpolation, using the first $m+1$ terms in the sequence as data.  Then, check that the formula works for all $n$ using induction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lagrange method for interpolation see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial